# How to update DB connection in GORM with new AWS token

Tags: go, authentication, amazon-rds, go-gorm

I have a gorm connection that I initially create by passing an AWS authentication token that expires every 15 minutes. The service will be able to connect to the DB for 15 minute. I have some functions for connecting to the db, for creating a new token, and for using a cron library to "refresh" the connection. I'm stuck in knowing how to actually provide the new token to GORM. I though of just doing `gorm.Open()` from within the cron job, but was told this would be bad because it'd not be thread safe, and would leave the old connections open. I was directed to this but I'm not sure what to do with it:
https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Connector

There is an example here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/3043#issuecomment-581931580

But I'm not sure what I'd replace the driver and connector code in that example for GORM. Anyhow.

Here's the code I have so far. First this connection function that wraps around gorm.Open:

```
func Connect(conf *config.DbConfig) (*gorm.DB, error) {
    host, port, err := net.SplitHostPort(conf.Host)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    sslMode := "require"
    if conf.DisableTLS {
        sslMode = "disable"
    }
    return gorm.Open(conf.Dialect,
        fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=%s",
            host, port, conf.Username, conf.Password, conf.Name, sslMode))
}
```

This is called in main like so:

```
        //IF WE WANT TO USE AWS TOKEN, REPLACE PW IN CONFIG WITH TOKEN
    if conf.DB.UseAwsToken {
        authToken, err := field.CreateAuthToken(&conf.DB)
        if err != nil {
            logger.Fatal(err)
        }
        conf.DB.Password = authToken
    }

       //CONNECT TO DB
    db, err := field.Connect(&conf.DB)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

      //INITIALIZE CRON JOB THAT RUNS IN SEPARATE THREAD TO REFRESH CONNECTION
       if conf.DB.UseAwsToken {
        processorCron := cron.New()

        cronInterval := "@every 10m"
        if conf.DB.CronInterval > 0 {
            cronInterval = fmt.Sprintf("@every %s", conf.DB.CronInterval)
        }

        processorCron.AddFunc(cronInterval, func() {
            repo.RenewDB(&conf.DB)
        })
        processorCron.Start()
    }
```

The part I'm stuck with the actual code for the RenewDB function, in the spot with the TODO:

```
type Repo struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

// FUNCTION 
func (r *Repo) RenewDB(dbConf *config.DbConfig) {
    var err error
    if dbConf.Password, err = CreateAuthToken(dbConf); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed at createAuthToken: %s\n", err.Error()))
    }

    //TODO: HOW DO I UPDATE GORM TO USE THE NEW AUTH TOKEN THAT I INSERTED
       // INTO dbConf?
}

//AUTH TOKEN GENERATOR
func CreateAuthToken(dbConf *config.DbConfig) (string, error) {
    awsSession, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    authToken, errToken := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(dbConf.Host, dbConf.AwsRegion, dbConf.Username, awsSession.Config.Credentials)
    if errToken != nil {
        return "", errToken
    }

    return authToken, nil
}
```

Comment: Whether this is even possible or not depends on your database, not GORM. If your database permits re-authenticating an active connection, you'll just need to send that command using raw SQL. Although doing so may be complicated by the connection pool.

Comment: @Flimzy that makes sense. I think that's what I'm struggling with. We're using Postgres and I'm just not sure how to reauthenticate the active connection through GORM's interface.

Comment: Are you sure PostgreSQL supports reauthentication? I've never heard of that in psql, but maybe it does...

Comment: Theres another service in our ecosystem that's using go-pg instead of gorm, and they are essentially pulling it off by packaging the authentication params in an object. The object is declared as a pointer as a global variable, and they have a cron routine that just overwrites the object. I'm just not sure if I can emulate this. Someone sent me this but I'm not what to do with it: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/3043#issuecomment-581931580

Comment: Sounds ugly, but if it works, it works, right?  I'm sure you can do the same with GORM.  I doubt it's "supported" (what you're doing with `go-pg` doesn't sound supported either), but with some ingenuity, I expect it can be done. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can use postgres with `pgx` as driver it can be achieved quite elegantly with a `beforeConnect` function:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "log/slog"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type tokenStruct struct {
    Token string
    ExpiresOn time.Time
}

func main() {

    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s port=%s", host, username, databaseName, port)

    config, err := pgx.ParseConfig(dsn)
    if err != nil {
        slog.Error("error while parsing db config", "error", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    db := stdlib.OpenDB(*config, stdlib.OptionBeforeConnect(refreshAccessToken()))

    gormDB, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{Conn: db}), &gorm.Config{})

    ...
}

func refreshAccessToken() func(ctx context.Context, config *pgx.ConnConfig) error {

    accessToken := tokenStruct{}

    return func(ctx context.Context, config *pgx.ConnConfig) error {
        if isExpired(accessToken) {
            var err error

            accessToken, err = getNewToken(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("failed to get new token: %w", err)
            }
            slog.Info("acquired new token for postgres", "expiry", accessToken.ExpiresOn)
        }

        config.Password = accessToken.Token
        return nil
    }
}

func getNewToken(ctx context.Context) (tokenStruct, error) {
    // get a fresh token
}

func isExpired(accessToken tokenStruct) bool {
    // expire the token a bit earlier, just to be safe
    oneMinuteInFuture := time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 1)
    return accessToken.ExpiresOn.Before(oneMinuteInFuture)
}
```