# Golang Pgx pool dynamic configuration

Tags: go, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance with postgres and I authenticate through IAM user. The password is a token that gets refreshed every 15 minutes:

```golang
    authToken, err := rdsutils.BuildAuthToken(Endpoint, "mars-east-4", "iamuser", envCredentials)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
```

However I already see the problem with connection Pooling throwing authentication errors after the token has expired and I did not find any good approach around.

What I was thinking is to create a function `GetPool` and inject it into my repository, this function will return a Pool object `pgxpool.Pool`:

```golang
func (p Pool) GetPool() (*pgxpool.Pool, error) {
    config, err := p.getConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    pool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return pool, nil
}
```

`getConfig` internally will call the `BuildAuthToken`, but only every 15 minutes (pseudocode):

```golang
if time > 15minutes {
  return BuildAuthToken()
}
```

So if the 15 minutes have passed I will re-fecth the token, otherwise I will use the one I already have.
This will be the final solution

```golang
func (p Pool) GetPool() (*pgxpool.Pool, error) {
    // Pseudocode
    if p.time < 15minutes {
      return p.Pool, nil
    }

    config, err := p.getConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    pool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    p.Pool = pool
    p.time = time.Now()
    return pool, nil
}
```

So is this approach inefficient? Is there a better approach? Also, since I will be using this in a server, how about race condition?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently pgx has introduced the `BeforeConnect` hook for the `pgxpool.Pool`

This is my current solution

```golang
func (p *Pool) getConfig() (*pgxpool.Config, error) {
    config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig("")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    /**
    This will refresh the password if the connection is expired
    */
    config.BeforeConnect = func(ctx context.Context, config *pgx.ConnConfig) error {
        if p.isTokenExpired() {
            creds, err := p.getCredentials()
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            config.User = creds.user
            config.Password = creds.password
            config.Host = creds.host
            config.Database = creds.database
            config.Port = creds.port
            p.cachedCredentials = creds
            p.expire = time.Now()
        } else {
            config.User = p.cachedCredentials.user
            config.Password = p.cachedCredentials.password
            config.Host = p.cachedCredentials.host
            config.Database = p.cachedCredentials.database
            config.Port = p.cachedCredentials.port
        }

        return nil
    }

    return config, nil
}
```

If the poll needs to create a new connection it will invoke first `BeforeConnect` hook, `getCredentials` will retrieve the token from AWS IAM, but this will happen only if the token is near its expiration time (15 minutes according to AWS)

**PS: this feature is not yet been released, but it is merged to the master. To use it you must get the latest commit**

Comment: this can also be used when using pgx through database/sql. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77287404